# How to do AFNetworking along with Heroku and iOS?

Tags: ios, heroku, afnetworking, server

I'm wanting to integrate Braintree or Stripe Payments into my app, and this requires a server to handle the processing because its a security risk if done in app. So my question is how do I connect my iOS app with my Heroku server that will have all of the node.js code?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a straight forward solution to this? I also just need to run simple business logic on a server for my mobile app and am wondering what stack to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question.
You have to create a public HTTP API that receives/sends JSON/XML on the server side.

On iOS side you have to create code for every request using AFNetworking.

Here's a quick tutorial to get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: would this help in integrating Braintree/Stripe?